# How to add string value of checkbox by using this.name to same array using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My problem is that I want to add the value of input-checkbox. This code is adding the value but not to the same array

```
$(".ticketAddition").change(function (){
    var name = [];
    name.toString();
    if (this.checked) {
        name.push(this.name);
        console.log(name);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you want to list the names of checked checkboxes?

Comment: Err... Have you tried moving `var name = [];` above `$(".ticketAddition").change(function (){`? Is that what you try to achieve?

Comment: Your line `name.toString();` does absolutely nothing.

Comment: name.toString() does nothing as the result isn't used anywhere

Comment: `this.name` is not the value of the checkbox, it is its name...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var name = [];
$(".ticketAddition").change(function (){
    name.toString(); // Why ?
    if (this.checked) {
        name.push(this.name);
        console.log(name);
    } else {
      name.splice(name.indexOf(this.name), 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: So what if it gets unchecked?

Comment: You remove (use `splice`) the name from the array.

Comment: I meant to say splice

Comment: Answers which explain what has changed and why are upvoted more often than those which simply say "try this"...

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over all the checked items to account for checking and unchecking alike:

```js
$(".ticketAddition").change(function (){
    var ticketSelection = [];
    $('.ticketAddition:checked').each(function() {
      ticketSelection.push(this.getAttribute('name'));
    });
    document.querySelector('#result').innerText = JSON.stringify(ticketSelection);
    // or console.log(ticketSelection)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="ticket_1" class="ticketAddition" /> Ticket #1</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="ticket_2" class="ticketAddition" /> Ticket #2</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="ticket_3" class="ticketAddition" /> Ticket #3</label></li>
</ul>

Checked tickets: <span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: what if not checked?
how to delete it, please?

Comment: Have you tried my provided code? It does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the checked checkbox using `:checked` selector. Use `map()` and `get()` to loop thru the checkboxes.

```js
$(".ticketAddition").change(function() {

  var names = $(".ticketAddition:checked").map(function() {
    return this.name;
  }).get();

  console.log(names)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="ticketAddition" name="apple" value="apple"> apple<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="ticketAddition" name="orange" value="orange"> orange<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="ticketAddition" name="pear" value="pear"> pear<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could instead get checked checkboxes inside your `.tickedAddition` element, where you map each element selected using `$(":checkbox:checked", this)` to its `value` attribute:

```js
$(".ticketAddition").change(function() {
  let names = $(":checkbox:checked", this).get().map(({value}) => value);
  console.log(names);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="ticketAddition">
  <label for="first">Frog</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="frog" name="cb" value="frog"/>
  <label for="first">Emu</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="emy" name="cb" value="emu"/>
  <label for="first">Bird</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="bird" name="cb" value="bird"/>
</form>
```